# Serialization issues when using Redis

Tags: java, serialization, redis, spring-data-redis

The application that I am working on uses Redis for cache management / session store. Problem that I frequently run into is a Serialization issue. Redis throws "doesn't implement serializable" Runtime exception frequently, sometime for application internal POJOs and sometimes for external library classes that I have integrated and using in my application.

Whenever I run into this Serializable runtime exception I will go to that class and make it implement Serializable and will modify the class based on Serializable contracts that is there. During this course, sometime I will encounter a complex classes which have many other dependencies too and thus it requires to correct all of them. Thing is my Application is huge and there are plenty of POJOs, now correcting all of them seems to be a tedious task, which makes me feel that some where this approach that I am following may not be correct. As I am new to this Redis thing, I am not sure how to go about this issue. Options that I have currently are:

1. Deploy application  every time and which ever class throws Serializable runtime exception, go and correct it the  redeploy.
2. Scan whole code base and correct all the classes that I feel must implement Serializable (mostly POJOs)

However, both the options seems tedious to me.

Edit :-
The application has a reddison.json file which has all the configuration details such as timeouts, retryattempts, redis address URL etc and in there defined is FSTcodec for serialization.

Added this to understand if I am using the wrong codec .

Comment: You may consider other codec's using **JsonJacksonCodec** or **TypedJsonJacksonCodec**

Comment: Will it ignore serialization??

Comment: Yes it does not require your objects to implement serializable.

Comment: It didn't work.. I am still running into Serialization issues

Comment: Can you share redisson.json file and code here